# Should a token be validated on every page change?

Tags: typescript, security, jwt, token

I have a little problem, I work on a react-native based app and I don't know if I should send a request to the server to validate the token every time I change the page / screen ( for instance 'feed' -> 'profile' ) or only when I send requests to the server

Answer (score 0):

Your UI is simply the UI, your calls to the server to pull data **should** be validated each time.

Your UI does not hold any data, so technically, they can see what it would look like without data.

For better user experience, a user should not see a url/button/link that they dont have access to. But from a security perspective, the only threat would be if your server side calls were not checking for authentication or authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You have a login request to get an access token then you save it on the client-side (cookie or other storage).

On the backend-side you have API with 2 request types:

1. Protected (eg GET /user/:id) - you should send the access token (backend checks it)
2. Open (eg GET /books)

On the client-side after changing screens in the best way you should have a protected route component and it checks the presence of the token in memory (or not after 401 status you should delete the token from memory). You have not to send a request for this purpose.